# Android ListView with a Custom Adapter - getChildAt() returns null

Tags: android-widget, android-listview, android

I have a ListView with a Custom Adapter, and I need to access the View of individual rows of this ListView. I am trying to do it using getChildAt(), but it is returning null.

Here's my ListView:

```
myListView = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listViewLayout);
```

This is the custom adapter:

```
    public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       ...
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, parent, false);
            }
            ...
    }
```

I create a List, and set it for the ListView:

```
List <String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("entry 1");
myList.add("entry 2");
myList.add("entry 3");
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myList);
myListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

Now, I want to access the View for individual rows.

```
View v = myListView.getChildAt(myListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

This v is null, no matter what. Additionally, `myListView.getChildCount()` always returns null.

What am I missing? Do I need to add the `convertView` to `parent` in `getView()`? Am I passing wrong parameters to `inflate`?

I have struggled a lot to figure this out. Please help me!

EDIT: I am posting the MyListAdapter class:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> myList;

    public MyListAdapter(Context c, List<String> m) {
        context = c;
        myList = m;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return myList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int pos = position;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, parent, false);
        }

            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
            text.setText(myList.get(pos));

            // Set the onClick Listener on this button
            Button rowButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemButton);

            //commenting next two lines makes the list row clickable
            rowButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            rowButton.setFocusable(false);

            rowButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, myList.get(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            });  
            convertView.setTag(pos);
            return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your implementation of getChildAt look like?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your MyListAdapter class? specifically, the constructor, the full body of getView and the implementation of getCount()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all probability you're doing all of this in `onCreate()`. Any view-related methods will return null (or empty) because the list has not been rendered yet. What do you need the child view for?

Comment: Each row has a TextView and a Button, and I need to change the visibility of individual buttons.

Comment: I am doing this in onResume(). I am trying getChildAt() only after setting the adapter...

Comment: Your thinking is flawed. As soon as the user scrolls your button visibility will go back to the default. You must set the appropriate visibility in your adapter's `getView()` method.

Comment: Yes, that could be a problem, but I intend to address it using getFirstVisiblePosition()... do you know why I am getting null from getChildAt()? :)

Comment: Like I said, it hasn't been rendered yet (being in `onResume()` does not guarantee this). And, are you going to call `getFirstVisiblePosition()` every time the user scrolls? You can't do it like that, it is _wrong_.

Comment: My requirements dictate this - the buttons need to become visible and invisible based on current time. I thought of running a thread to check current time (with sleep), and set Button visibility for the required rows. Do you have any recommendations for accomplishing this?

Comment: If I do it from my thread, after a 500 millisecond sleep, it works. I still want to know the 'right' way though.

Comment: If you call `notifyDatasetChanged()` from your adapter every 500 ms and you calculate whether or not the button should be visible in your `getView()`, you should get the effect that you want. 500ms seems a bit extreme though.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot for your help. I will try that out. 500 ms is extreme, I will eventually change it to 5 seconds.

Comment: in my opinion, every answer concerning `listview.getChildCount()`should start with "dont do it in onCreate". thanks @dmon.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of extending the BaseAdapter, to use the ArrayAdapter class. With the BaseAdapter, I believe that you have to maintain both the list of objects and the views themselves. So something like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{ 
...
}
```

Then you would create the class like this.

```
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row_layout, myList);
```

**Updated** 
Also, in your constructor, you are not calling your base class constructor.

Comment: I am afraid I am not getting it. ListAdapter is an interface, I tried implementing it, without any different results. Calling super() in the constructor also has no effect. Do I need to try super.getView()? That doesn't work for the adapter...

Comment: Opps, sorry. I put in the wrong class name. It should have been ArrayAdapter rather than ListAdapter. Updated my solution.